# To display data in a label with limited character

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net

I am trying to display data in a label with 100 character in first row and next 100 character below first line.
Reading data from database and displaying it on a label with 100 character on first row.next 100 below that and so on.

```
lblSpec.InnerText = ReadData["spec"].ToString();
```

.ASPX displaying it on label

```
   <tr id="lblReqTr" runat="server"><td style="font-size:10pt"><div><b> Requirement</b></div></td><td><div><label id='lblSpec' rows="3" Size="50" runat="server"></label></div></td></tr>
```

eg.
showing 10 character in a row next 10 below it

```
hi i am om

you are pm

radha girl
```

Comment: split the text with .match(/.{1,3}/g) then join with "<br>" then add back as inlinehtml?

Comment: It will difficult to use HTML label as multiline. Are you able to use ASP Label instead of HTML label? So i can help to achieve this.

Comment: @Jitendra yes i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below logic as per your requirement.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label id='lblSpec' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

C#:

```
string data = ReadData["spec"].ToString();
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@".{100}");
lblSpec.Text = regex.Replace(data, "$& <br/>");
```